# correre [a] oppure [da]?

Tags: prepositions

Soprattutto mi confondo dell'uso del preposizione **`da`** negli questi situazioni :

Per esempio, nella questa frasi sequenti :

> "Ho dimenticato il mio gatto nella macchina, devo correre **da** lui"
>
> "Ieri sono andato **dal** dottore"

Penso lo che dovessi "**a**" invece, considerando la mia madrelingua, cosi non comprendo logica bene. Perché ci sono le ***mire*** **a** dirigersi verso, ma non **da** dirigersi. Mi puoi dire di più sul questo argomento per favore ?

Comment: Complimenti per il tuo italiano, ma ci sono un po' di imprecisioni. Ne parlo qui anziché correggere la domanda perché sia più facile il confronto.
«Mi confonde molto l'uso della preposizione "da" in certe situazioni, per esempio, nelle frasi seguenti : "Ho dimenticato il gatto in macchina, devo correre da lui" "Ieri sono andato dal dottore" Penserei di dover usare "a", considerando la mia madrelingua, quindi non mi è ben chiara la logica. Perché [ci sono le mire a dirigersi verso, ma non da dirigersi][?? Non sono sicuro di capire...]. Mi potete dire di più su questo argomento, per favore?»

Comment: Thank you @DaG I meant "directing to a target should have a preposition **a** (to) instead of **da** (from)" logically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bella domanda!

La preposizione *da*, con verbi di moto, indica molto spesso provenienza, ma non sempre: il significato **1** [nella voce del dizionario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/da/) mostra infatti l'uso principale, ma prosegue

> **2.** Introduce anche altri complementi di luogo: il moto a luogo (solo con nomi o pronomi di persona): *verrò oggi stesso da te*; *devo andare dal sarto*; *scendo dal tabaccaio*; il moto attraverso luogo, soprattutto in locuzioni col verbo passare: *è tanto grasso che non passa dalla porta*. Con verbi di quiete (complemento di stato in luogo), si adopera per lo più davanti a nomi di persona: *sono stato dall’avvocato*; *ti attendo dal meccanico*; *mi servo dal droghiere qui di fronte*; *frequenta l’asilo dalle suore*; *sarò a cena da mio zio*; *da noi non c’è quest’uso* (in questi ultimi casi equivale in genere a: «presso»); o con i nomi lato, parte: *la cornice è scrostata da un lato*; *la stoffa è da una parte grigia, dall’altra verde*; *da ogni parte del paese si vede il castello*; *abito anch’io da quelle parti* (qui indica approssimativamente il luogo, e la locuzione può anche dipendere da verbi di moto: *vado da quelle parti*, *proviene da quelle parti*).

Quindi *vado a teatro*, *vado al mare*, ma nessuno direbbe mai **vado al dottore*. Però *vado all’ambulatorio del dottore*.

In realtà “solo con nomi o pronomi di persona” non sembra descrivere completamente l'uso, come nell’esempio del gatto.

“Le mire a dirigersi” è un tipo diverso di complemento e non indica moto.

Comment: Grazie mille per spiegazione ricca ! Ho apprezzato molto ...